# filesystem parent path and a ".." string to get back to parent path

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17, subdirectory, directory-structure

Im not using boost, im using C++17's filesystem which is basically based on boosts filesystem.

I want to list directories, filenames and parent directory shortcut ".." using C++ filesystem.
I have no problem adding directories and filenames to a list, I do it this way:

```
string path="C:\something\test";

//add missing code here:
//should find: ".." or not.

//add directories to list
for (auto& p : directory_iterator(path))
{
    if (p.is_directory())
    {
        string name = p.path().filename().string();
        list[index].push_back(name);
    }
}

//add files to list
for (auto& p : directory_iterator(path))
{
    if (!p.is_directory())
    {
        string filename = p.path().filename().string();   //hele filnavnet (med filtype)
        list[index].push_back(filename);
    }
}
```

This is working well and fine, but the problem is im missing the ".." if i am in a sub-directory like C:\something\test\ path. I want to find out wether or not there is a parent path available, whats the easiest way to do this using filesystem?

And also the same thing if the path is "C:", then my program should say that ".." is not available.
Basically the list could be looking like something like this if i am in C:\something\test\

```
..
AnotherDirectory
YetAnotherDirectory
file1.txt
file2.txt
etc.txt
```

and if i am in "C:"
a list would look something like this (without the "..")

```
Something
Directory2
file1.txt
command.com
autoexec.but
config.lol
```

Comment: Can't you use [`std::filesystem::path::parent_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path) for this?

Comment: How would that work? The problem is that parent_path().string() doesnt give me ".." when i am in "C:\" for example. it gives the same name. Hm. maybe I can check wether the subdir is equal to parent_path() that might be an idea I didnt think of actually..

Comment: `"...check wether the subdir is equal to parent_path()"` -- exactly.  Just a guess though.  Haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

I got this idea from @G.M.

```
if (fs::current_path() != fs::current_path().parent_path())
    MessageBox(NULL, ".. exists", "Message", MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(NULL, ".. doesn't exist", "Message", MB_OK);
```

This was a hacky approach that works, but I don't know any easier or better method.